# Channel API and server affinity

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

As GAE instances are added and removed how does the Channel API work to maintain a connection between a server and a client browser. That is, does a single server maintain the connection and is solely responsible for pushing out messages to the client browser. Or is any server able to send data on the channel, and if so how is the channel state maintained across all the servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to worry about any of that.

Any server instance can send data to a channel if it know the client ID, regardless of what server created it etc. That's it.

Plus with the 1.7.5 release you get this:

> The Channel API now has the ability to send channel messages from any app version or backend regardless of where the channel was created.

So you can use backends now with the channel API without any workarounds.

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes